# How to build graph on trip count and from and to station

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

I'm totally new to Neo4j, trying to build a directed graph from source train stations to destination train stations. I have a file whose SS is as attached, with trip counts, my target is to build a nodes and edges graph which will show all stations and trip directions with counts.

I've downloaded Neo4J desktop, loaded by CSV file. I've not used Cypher before, so wondering how to structure it down to code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: h]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're going to want to think about what your data model looks like. You may find the following helpful for this:

- [An introduction to graph modelling](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/)
- Also, [Arrows](http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/#) might be useful for modelling, but of course, a sheet of paper is equally useful

A hint to get you started, whilst you have origin and destination, you may find that they're both going to be the same type of node (e.g. TrainStation, TrainStationCode), and you use the direction of your relationships to suggest whether that node is an origin or a destination.

Once you've settled on your data model, you will want to identify which are your nodes and relationships from your CSV file. Check out the following to help you import your data:

- [Importing a CSV](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/)
- You may find Mark's blog post on [avoiding eager queries](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) useful, especially if you have a large data set.

The following posts, whilst might not be what you're working on, might be an interesting read for you:

- [Journey planning](https://neo4j.com/blog/journey-planning-why-i-love-cypher/)
- [Modelling flights](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/08/26/modeling-airline-flights-in-neo4j/)

Comment: Your answer is quite helpful, I could understand how to go about it. The model is already in my mind, but I am not being able to write it down in Cypher. That's why this question. I mean, how to set both source and destination stations unique nodes and then connect them (by building directed relationship) row by row.

Comment: Using the 'avoiding eager queries' post as a guide, you will most likely do two passes of the CSV to load the data. The first pass will be to load just the stations, the second pass will be to a) look up the stations, and then b) create a relationship between them. I'd also suggest thinking about setting your indexes ahead of time too - most likely on the origin_code (assuming that is unique)

Comment: e.g. first pass - LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS row WITH row MERGE (:Station {name:row.origin, code:row.origin_code}) MERGE (:Station {name:row.destination, code:row.destination_code})

Comment: e.g. second pass - LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS row WITH row MATCH (origin:Station {code:row.origin_code}), (destination:row.destination_code}) CREATE (origin)-[:HAS_JOURNEY_TO {tripCount:row.trip_count}]->(destination)

Comment: One silly query, why do I need to read the data everytime I write a query? Doesn't it store in memory as a dataframe or something like in Python pandas or Spark?

Comment: Not silly at all! You could have re-written the query so that you only run the LOAD CSV bit once. However, the engine would behave very eagerly, assuming that everything might be needed later on, which can require a lot of memory. Splitting out like above avoids this. I would heartily recommend you read Mark's blog to understand what's happening

Comment: Sure I would. I actually went through most of the links you've shared already. BTW this were the steps I wrote down, where do you think I went wrong? Step 1)
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///trips_aggregated.csv" AS row CREATE (n:trainMapping {sourceStationCode: row.origin_code, sourceStationName: row.origin, destinationStationCode: row.destination_code, destinationStationName: row.destination, tripCount: toInt(row.trip_count)});

Step 2)
CREATE INDEX ON :trainMapping(sourceStationName);

Step 3)
CREATE INDEX ON :trainMapping(destinationStationName);

Comment: Step 4)

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///trips_aggregated.csv" AS row
MATCH (sourceStation:sourceStationCode {sourceStationCode: row.origin_code})
MATCH (destinationStation:destinationStationCode {destinationStationCode: row.destination_code})
MERGE (sourceStation)-[:TRIP_TO]->(destinationStation);

Comment: I would recommend (unless there is something specific with your usecase) not to use different property names for your trainMapping node labels, e.g. do not use sourceStationCode/Name, stick to just stationCode/Name

Comment: Now, I've edited the relationships from the above with time taken column and want to see all 2 hop paths between the same stations. Eg: JPTS->ABCD->EFG->JPTS. Did this: MATCH (jpts_src:Station { name: 'JPTS' })-[*2]->(jpts_dest:Station { name: 'JPTS' })
CREATE (jpts_src)-[:`Two_Hop_Relation`]->(jpts_dest). But the result gives only one node and nothing else. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is now about query the data rather than importing the data. I would suggest if you're satisfied with the answer on imports you close it off and create a new question on querying your data so that other people can benefit if they have a similar query.

Comment: Here's the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750038/constraint-based-querying-in-neo4j